# Handling SQLCMD Errors within PowerShell Task in SQL Job

Tags: sql-server

I've scheduled a PowerShell task within a SQL job on a SQL Server instance. The task involves executing SQLCMD within the PowerShell script. However, regardless of whether SQLCMD executes with or without errors (e.g., using a non-existent server name), the job always reports a successful outcome.

Here is an example of the PowerShell script within the SQL job:

```
#get database connections
$Query = "select value from rubrikAPItoken where name = 'token'"
$token = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance servername.internal.mcmcg.com -Database dba_stats -Query $Query

# Connect to Rubrik
function connectTo-Rubrik(){
    return Connect-Rubrik -Server rubserver -Token $token.value
}

# Start of script
Import-Module Rubrik -Verbose

# Connect to Rubrik
$connection = connectTo-Rubrik

# Select Managed Volume
$ManagedVolume = Get-RubrikManagedVolume -Name servername-full-mv -Verbose

# Check if Drive is not writeable
if(!$ManagedVolume.isWritable){
    # If not writeable, enable writing
    $ManagedVolume | Start-RubrikManagedVolumeSnapshot -Verbose
}

###################### Run MSSQL Backup ######################

try {
    sqlcmd -E -S servername -d DBA_STATS -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] @Databases = 'SYSTEM_DATABASES', @Directory = N'\\10.110.123.227\servername-sys-mv_channel0_29fe2c98,\\10.110.123.241\servername-sys-mv_channel1_29fe2c98,\    \10.110.123.223\servername-sys-mv_channel2_29fe2c98,\\10.110.123.230\servername-sys-mv_channel3_29fe2c98', @BackupType = 'FULL', @Verify = 'Y', @CleanupTime = 240, @Compress='Y', @CheckSum = 'Y'" -b    

    ##############################################################

    # Check to see if connection is available
    if(([datetime]$connection.value.datetime).AddMinutes(15) -le (Get-Date)){
        $connection = connectTo-Rubrik
    }

    # Stop Snapshot
    $ManagedVolume | Stop-RubrikManagedVolumeSnapshot -Verbose

    # Disconnect Rubrik
    Disconnect-Rubrik
}
catch{
    # Check to see if connection is available
    if(([datetime]$connection.value.datetime).AddMinutes(15) -le (Get-Date)){
        $connection = connectTo-Rubrik
    }

    # Stop Snapshot
    $ManagedVolume | Stop-RubrikManagedVolumeSnapshot -Verbose
}
```

The issue is that even when SQLCMD encounters an error, such as with an incorrect server name, the job outcome is marked as successful. I've tried using try/catch blocks to handle the errors, but it doesn't seem to work within the SQL job context. Any suggestions on how to handle errors generated by SQLCMD within the PowerShell script in a way that reflects the correct job outcome in SQL Server?

Comment: `sqlcmd.exe` is not a PowerShell cmdlet so why would you expect it to throw an exception? Even if it did throw an exception the code is catching any exception that might occur and swallowing the result. Have you considered: a) using `Start-Process` with the `-PassThru -Wait` options; b) capturing the process object returned from `Start-Process` and checking its `$_.ExitCode`; and c) signalling an error to SQL Agent with `$host.SetShouldExit($yourCustomExitCodeNumber)` and `exit $yourCustomExitCodeNumber`?

Comment: thank you for feedback. Do you think invoke-sqlcmd might work? and example code or tweak my code is appreciated.